# jQuery download all files within list

Tags: jquery, download

Is it possible to download all files within in a ul list, with a button or link, using jQuery?

```
<ul>
  <li> <a href="/downloads/1231/file-01.zip">file-01.zip</a> </li>
  <li> <a href="/downloads/5432/file-02.jpg">file-02.jpg</a> </li>
  <li> <a href="/downloads/2234/file-03.pdf">file-03.pdf</a> </li>
</ul>
<a href="#">Download all files</a>
```

Would be nice if they could be zipped, but not necessary (could just download multiple files).

I've seen the following https://github.com/biesiad/multiDownload

```
<ul>
  <li> <a id="1" href="/downloads/1231/file-01.zip">file-01.zip</a> </li>
  <li> <a id="2" href="/downloads/5432/file-02.jpg">file-02.jpg</a> </li>
  <li> <a id="3" href="/downloads/2234/file-03.pdf">file-03.pdf</a> </li>
</ul>
<a id='t' href="">trigger</a>

  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $('#1').multiDownloadAdd();
    $('#2').multiDownloadAdd();
    $('#3').multiDownloadAdd();
    $('#t').multiDownload('click');
  </script>
```

However, my download lists will have varying amounts of list items within them, and I will have multiple download lists on the same page.

I need some code that could count all items within the list, and add them to the 'multiDownloadAdd'

There needs to be a method that will allow only the files within same UL to download together.

Also the server creates a folder for each download, so each file has a separate folder.

Comment: tell us what you have done so far

Answer (score 0):

Create a archive or zip of all the multiple files and just use it like this `<a href="/download/file.zip">Download all files</a>`.

If the file list is dynamic, then use this [javascript plugin](http://gildas-lormeau.github.com/zip.js/) for creating the zip file and provide the link for the same in the html page.